# How to rewrite route with NPM serve

Tags: node.js, npm, serve

Hello I'm using the [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) npm package. I am trying to serve static files on a different route.
Let's say I have the following directory structure that I'm trying to serve:

- index.html
- index.js
- helpers

  - helper.js

I'm trying to serve it on a specific route using the serve package, but I can't seem to get the rewrite syntax correct. I'm trying to serve it on the `custom` route.
What I have as the config is:

```
{
  "rewrites": [
    {"source":"custom/**", "destination":""}
  ]
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need export your server and call baseURL

in **helper**

```
export const server = {
 baseURL: 'http:localhost:3000'
}
```

i expect that resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm confident that empty string will throw serve for a loop.

Try:

```json
{
  "rewrites": [
    {"source":"custom/**", "destination":"/**"}
  ]
}
```

That assumes your folder structure is in the same folder you told serve to operate on. You would change the destination if your files were in a different folder.

Eg:

```
$ pwd
/var/web/site

$ ls
old_files/ index.html

$ ls old_files
index.html index.js helpers/
```

Your config should be:

```json
{
  "rewrites": [
    {"source":"custom/**", "destination":"/old_files/**"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does this actually work?

Comment: It is currently-used code for my developers' development environment. I'll check that our code still matches what I shared.